# awk: change line to itself parsed with command. Multiline text

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, xml

I'm trying to answer a question. It involves using the command `recode`. A specific line has to be parsed by the command leaving the rest untouched. The file is an `xml` file. Example:

```html
    <ITEM_ID>foo</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>bar</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION><p>foo</p><p> </p><p> </p></DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>bar</URL>
    <IMGURL>foo</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
```

The desired output should be:

```html
    <ITEM_ID>foo</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>bar</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>bar</URL>
    <IMGURL>foo</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
```

---

NOTE: The command `recode` works as intended. Avoiding the conversion of the tags `DESCRIPTION` can be solved later, is not part of the question.

The line that should be changed is the one that starts with `<DESCRIPTION>`.

I'm really bad at `awk` still, the intended command would be something like this:

```bsh
awk '/<DESCRIPTION>/ { $0 = print $0 "| recode ..html" }1' foo.txt
```

which of course doesn't work.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: What is that awk command supposed to be doing? Are you trying to pass the first field through `recode`? The entire line? A file? How would you do this with `echo string |recode` if you didn't need to use `awk`?

Comment: @terdon The entire line. With `echo` would be `echo "<DESCRIPTION><p>foo</p><p> </p><p> </p></DESCRIPTION>" | recode ..html`, which output would be: `&lt;DESCRIPTION&gt;&lt;p&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/DESCRIPTION&gt;`.

Comment: @terdon the command I put as example is a very ugly representation of what I'm trying to accompĺish, `awk` is still a mistery to me, in fact is almost gibberish, I'm trying so many things...

Comment: That's what's confusing me. If I run `echo "<DESCRIPTION><p>foo</p><p> </p><p> </p></DESCRIPTION>" | recode ..html`, I get something completely and utterly different (it converts to html codes for chinese characters) than what you show. I can give you the awk command for it, but it doesn't seem to be what you need at all.

Comment: @terdon Mmh, there's something there the with depending on the locale. OP of the original question (askubuntu) run mi firts attemtp (without `awk`), using `recode`, and did'nt had this charset/locale problem. If you want to pass the command, maybe will shed some light.

Comment: @steeldriver is `getline` a gawk thing? I just tested and saw my answer fails with mawk, so it may well be, but are you sure?

Comment: @terdon getline is portable to all awks, getline with coprocesses is gawk-specific. However, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use awk's `getline` to read the output into a variable. You also need to set the locale correctly for the recoding to work as expected. Try this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C gawk '/DESCRIPTION/{
        "echo \""$0"\" | recode ..html" | getline ff; print ff
       }' file 
    &lt;DESCRIPTION&gt;&lt;p&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/DESCRIPTION&gt;
```

Comment: For the command to be compĺete, to print the whole file, you need to add the `}1`, although it prints the `DESCRIPTION` twice, one parsed and the other not. The output desired is the whole file, and the selected line changed.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity that wasn't part of the question. I am just showing how to pass an awk variable to a shell command and then retrieve the output and use it in awk. Adding `}1`wouldn't be enough anyway, you would want something like: `awk '/DESCRIPTION/{"echo \""$0"\" | recode ..html" | getline $0;}1' file` which would save the output to `$0` and then allow you to print it normally.

Comment: You seem to encode the entire `DESCRIPTION` node, not just its value.

Comment: Save the shell command in a variable so you can close it after every line processed otherwise YMMV with trying to read the command output 1 line at a time. You should also protect the call to getline so it doesn't silently reprint the previously successful value on a failure and you should be using single quotes, not double, around the $0 in the echo command being given to shell.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, because that's what the question asked for: *"NOTE: The command recode works as intended. Avoiding the conversion of the tags DESCRIPTION can be solved later, is not part of the question."*.

Comment: it should be written as `cmd="echo \047" $0 "\047 | recode ..html"; ff=( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "ERROR" ); print ff; close(cmd)` or similar depending whether or not you want an error message if/when the pipe fails.

Comment: @terdon Aha, I didn't understand that part of the question. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the document is well formed, with some root node `root`...

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
    <ITEM_ID>foo</ITEM_ID>
    <PRODUCTNAME>bar</PRODUCTNAME>
    <DESCRIPTION><p>foo</p><p> </p><p> </p></DESCRIPTION>
    <URL>bar</URL>
    <IMGURL>foo</IMGURL>
    <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE></IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
</root>
```

Then,

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '/root/DESCRIPTION' -v "$( xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/root/DESCRIPTION/*' file.xml )" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <ITEM_ID>foo</ITEM_ID>
  <PRODUCTNAME>bar</PRODUCTNAME>
  <DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;foo&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;</DESCRIPTION>
  <URL>bar</URL>
  <IMGURL>foo</IMGURL>
  <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE/>
</root>
```

What's happening here is that `xmlstarlet sel` is used to extract the a copy of the nodes under the `/root/DESCRIPTION` node.  This is what `xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/root/DESCRIPTION/*' file.xml` does, and it returns the string `<p>foo</p><p> </p><p> </p>`.

This string is then used as the new text value for the `/root/DESCRIPTION` node by means of an `xmlstarlet ed` command.  The new value is had from a command substitution.

Note that the value is automatically XML encoded.